# Не происходит завершение функции после return

Tags: javascript, return

Есть код:

```
function checkUser(ctx) {
  let fileData = [1, 2, 3];
  fileData.forEach(element => {
    if (element == userId) {
      console.log("true");
      return element;
    }
  });
  console.log("false");
  return false;
}
```

Я ожидал увидить в консоли *false* или *true*. Но вместо *true* вижу *true false* вместе. Почему?

Comment: первый `return` у Вас для коллбэка метода `forEach`, а не для функции `checkUser`. Если что, то  цикл `forEach` прервать нельзя. Либо пользуйтесь обычным `for`, либо специальными  методами массивов `some` и `every`

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом `find` вместо `forEach`. Ну или `some`, да, в этом случае должно быть достаточно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте for

```js
let fileData = [1, 2, 3],
    userId = 3;
function checkUser(fileData, userId) {
   
  for (let element of fileData) {
    if (element == userId) {
      console.log("true");
      return element;
    }
  }
  console.log("false");
  return false;
};


checkUser(fileData, userId);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Найдено даже два ответа.

1) Так как первый return относится к foreach, то можно использовать some или every.
@Дмытрык

2) Для моего конкретного случая идеально подходит find вместо б.
@smellyshovel

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkUser(ctx) {
let fileData = [1, 2, 3];
  for(let element of fileData){
    if (element == userId) {
      console.log("true");
      return element;
    }
  }
  console.log("false");
  return false;
}
```